# How can I fix this stored card status: merchant is not authorized to use store card api in PayU payment gateway?

Tags: android, payumoney

Why show this message how to fix this

[image: payupayment pages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed showing error toast. Here commented the toast messgae..

```
  if (payuResponse.isResponseAvailable() && payuResponse.getResponseStatus().getCode() == PayuErrors.NO_ERROR) { // ok we are good to go
           // Toast.makeText(this, payuResponse.getResponseStatus().getResult(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```